# Any ways to disable sleep tracking on Garmin Enduro 2?

Tags: gear

Basically it keeps telling me my sleep is poor(gotta wake up during the night to check that stuff is running properly sometimes). It's not a huge issue, but maybe anyone knows a way to completely disable sleep mode?

Edit1: It's a sports watch with a bunch of added options(monitoring recovery, stress, heart rate+ maps for outdoor stuff).

Comment: You can customize your sleep hours (menu>system>sleep)  - perhaps you can set them to be midnight to 0001 am?

Comment: Okay, this actually works, just had to "reduce" sleep hours to 1 minute basically. Thanks!

Comment: @bob1 perhaps you should make that an answer, so it can be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the solution here (as per comments between me and OP) is to change the sleep time settings to the minimum amount you can, which appears to be 1 minute. This might well work on any Garmin device that has similar functionality, such as the Fenix-7.

To do this, access the main "menu", select "settings" and then "sleep" and finally schedule (Menu > Settings > Sleep > Schedule). Full instructions can be found in the manual for the [Garmin Enduro 2](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/GUID-2CD92989-7336-4BF3-96CC-50DDBD63B109/EN-US/GUID-10B3BD3D-5B72-4C4F-9B2D-93432AF67E43.html).

Answer (score 1):

As it is a watch, take it off your wrist and it should stop recording what you do.

If it starts beeping you can avoid being annoyed by it through putting it in a drawer in a different room.

Comment: *" in a different room."* But that's... indoors! Seriously though, I had to deal with unstoppable beeping by packing a phone with a broken touchscreen in foam, in a wooden box, more foam, in a heavy cupboard, downstairs, with 2 closed doors.  I could still hear the alarm going off if I was already awake.  Besides, people who buy smart watches are likely to  want to use some of their other features overnight, like alarms (even vibrating alarms to avoid awaking a partner work better strapped to you).  But hopefully just  taking it off is an option

Comment: Yeah, I kinda rely on alarm and some other stuff, so it's not really an option to simply put 'em away. On top of that, okay, while at home it might be an option on weekend when I don't need 'em but while camping/hiking - not really. Hence why I just want to turn off that feature

Comment: But what does it do if you sleep with it next to your head - could you use an audible alarm? I find it uncomfortable to sleep in a watch anyway, and I know I'm not alone, so taking it off to sleep should be considered normal by the manufacturer. Anyway a device that's supposed to help with your sleep quality shouldn't be built to disturb you at night!

Comment: This:  "*a device that's supposed to help with your sleep quality shouldn't be built to disturb you at night!*"